# Can not connect MSSQL 2005 from Android Device

Tags: android

I am using
Eclipse 
MS SQL SERVER 2005
Android 4.2.2 device 
jtds-1.2.6. jar

I am adding jar file to
Project->Properties->Java Build Path-> Add External jars after that check ORDER and EXPORT
INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK is ALLOW
MINIMUM SDK=4

```
void Connect()
{
  try 
  {
      Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
  } 
  catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
  {
    tv.setText("3"+e.getMessage());
  } 
  try 
  {
    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(
                 "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.103:1433/DB","sa","1");

    Statement query = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery("select NAME  from Student");
    String yazi = "";
    while (rs.next()) 
    {
      tv.setText(rs.getString(0));
    }
     conn.close();

    } 
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
      tv.setText("4"+e.getMessage());
    }
    catch(Exception ee)
    {
      tv.setText("7"+ee.toString());
    }
 }
```

When I run program to Device it stops at
`DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.103:1433/DB","sa","1");`

What is the Problem?

Comment: Besides this being a colossally bad idea (IMO, as opposed to creating a server side API the client device can hit via HTTP or such, though there are times it is necessary I suppose), you'll have to provide more info if you want meaningful help. What do you mean "it is stop at"? Do you have an actual error message, or some logs? What do the error outputs you are putting into TextViews say, if anything? (And you know you can log those errors in logcat right, rather than use views on the screen?)

Comment: Please post yuor logcat output, it's likely to be hidden in the stack trace

Comment: @Merlin What is the best way Data process Ms Sql server with Android.
.Net Web Service or JTDS or another?

Comment: @NoNameNoSurname it's best to abstract from calling the database directly. It doesn't matter if you're using webservices or some homemade interface. What matters is that you abstract from calling the database directly. A webservice or something else can take care of a lot of problems like timeouts and such for you.

Comment: Absolutely. Wireless connections are completely unreliable which would break a lot of the functionality of a dedicated network-SQL connection. You absolutely need to consider asynchronous communications which, in my preference, would mean some kind of web-service.